# Object doesn't get constructed

Tags: c++, object, operator-overloading, construction

I've noticed this weird behaviour/bug where a class method is called *before* the actual object is initialized. I have a wrapper object, which has `operator->()` method. Now, when I'm passing the object to another object as constructor parameter in a constructor using the `operator->()` method, the actual wrapper object doesn't get constructed, but rather just runs the `operator->()` method.

As the actual code sample is pretty complicated and depends on many other things, I'll just show C++ code snippet which may not compile properly:

```
template<typename T>
class wrapper_object_type
{
public:
    wrapper_object_type() {/*does not run*/}
    T* operator->() {/*does run*/}
};
class bad_behaviour
{
public:
    bad_behaviour() : another_object(wrapper_object->t_object) 
    {/*crashes(0xccc access violation*/}
};
```

So is there something defined in the standard that may allow such behaviour? Or more accurately, are there some implicit constructions etc. which could bypass the default construction?

Comment: Your code snippet is fairly nonsensical.

Comment: Where does `wrapper_object` come from in the `bad_behaviour` constructor?

Comment: The `wrapper_object` is inside the `bad_behaviour` class, and the `wrapper_object_type` class has a static instance for the `T` type. The `wrapper_object_type` class acts as a shared instance which is fairly similar to `boost::shared_from_this`

Comment: What type is `another_object`?

Comment: @Steve Well it's just an arbitrary object, which takes the `t_object` as parameter. In the code where the actual crash happens, it's boost.asio's `tcp::acceptor` object.

Comment: @weggo What order are `another_object` and `wrapper_object` declared in the `bad_behavior` class?  If `another_object` is declared first then I don't believe that `wrapper_object`'s constructor will have yet been executed, if it is an object.  If `wrapper_object` is a pointer type, then you're simply dealing with the fact that `wrapper_object` has not yet been initialized.

Comment: @cdhowie Yeah it's not pointer, it's an object allocated into stack. I also tried to explicitly construct the `wrapper_object` before calling the operator overload member function.

Comment: Your question is not self contained.  The code you provided doesn't compile, and your problem exists in the code you didn't provide.  Please provide an example which actually compiles: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

Probably you use `wrapper_object` before it gets initialized. Member variables are constructed in the same order in which they are declared in the class, so make sure `wrapper_object` is declared before `another_object`.

(Assuming `wrapper_object` and `another_object` are members variables of `bad_behaviour`, but without a more reasonable code sample it's hard to say.)

Comment: The `wrapper_object` should be initialized, because the `->` is just a call to the overloaded operator. For what I understand about C++, the object is at least implicitly constructed before the member functions can be used. (I did try explicitly construct it aswell before calling the member function)

Comment: @weggo All of the objects are at least constructed before entering the *constructor*, but not the *initializer list*.  You are using a member from the initializer list, so you *must* ensure that the member you are using is declared before the member you are initializing, otherwise the compiler will emit the construction code for the used member *after* you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did it the hardway; I switched the objects from stack to heap and initialized them explicitly via `new` keyword rather than in initializer list. As I thought, that didn't reproduce the weird behaviour, so it worked as intended. What I'm thinking now, is that it may be actually a compiler bug, since the way I did it via initializer list is analog to how I fixed the problem. Only thing that changed was the fact that I didn't allocate them in heap before.

I also tried to provide working code which reproduces the bug, but the bug wasn't shown there. It may be because the actual code where the bug was noticed, relies quite heavily to template types and wrapper objects. As it works now when the objects are allocated in heap, the bug isn't in the code but rather in the compiler.